# Como fazer uma matriz associativa em python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matriz

Possuo um código que pede uma matriz `8x8`, mas preciso que no `input` ele peça os valores assim:

```
matriz [A][1]: 

matriz [A][2]:
```

Ou seja, que ele peça a linha em forma de letra e a coluna em forma de número.

Até agora só consegui fazer ele aparecer a linha e coluna em forma de número, assim:

```
matriz [1][1]:

matriz [1][2]:
```

Comment: Poderia [edit] a pergunta e adicionar o código que possui?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O python possui a função [chr](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#chr), ela retorna um caracter a partir de um número inteiro. Para o alfabeto maiúsculo, esse número começa com 65 (A) e acaba em 90 (Z).

```
>>> chr(65)
   'A'
>>> chr(90)
   'Z'
```

O contrário desta função é o [ord](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#ord).

```
>>> ord('A')
   65
>>> chr('Z')
   90
```

Para printar `matriz [A][1]:` a partir de um `i=0` e `j=0`, é só fazer:

`print('matriz [{}][{}]: '.format(chr(65+i),j+1))`

Comment: valeeu!!! consegui por esse método

Comment: @LetíciaGabrielaCena, se a resposta foi satisfatória para você marque-a como aceita. Assim você e o autor da resposta ganham pontos :)

Answer (score 0):

Você pode trabalhar diretamente com um dicionário, ou seja:

```
matriz_assoc = {
        "a": [ 1, 2, 3, ],
        "b": [ 4, 5, 6, ],
        "c": [ 7, 8, 9, ]
    }
```

E para acessar seu conteúdo você usará:

```
print(matriz_assoc["a"][0])
1
```

Claro, em memória o Python não guardará a ordem dos itens do teu dicionário, assim, para imprimi-la, use algo assim:

```
for linha in sorted(matriz_assoc.keys()):
    print(matriz_assoc[linha])
```

Para gerar uma saída na ordem correta.